# Why is the Toolbar not showing the title and Settings?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am working with a `DrawerLayout` and on press of one of the item, I want to show a `Toolbar` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`. Because, Android's standard ActionBar creates problems with `ToolBar`, I decided to use an Activity with `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` instead and decided to use a `ToolBar` instead of an `ActionBar`.

Now, there is one normal `Toolbar` that serves as an `ActionBar` and as I click on one of the items from the drawer, I want to display a `Fragment` with another custom `Toolbar` replacing the "normal" `Toolbar`. So, I did that, removing the normal `Toolbar` but the Toolbar that is displaying now is without the title and overflow menu:

[image]

You can see the layout hierarchy here. The `Toolbar` is buried inside several `ViewGroup`s and its not properly displaying. Although it's displaying like this, the Drawer layout is opening and closing on clicking the Home menu in the Toolbar. Again, the icon doesn't change on Drawer open/close.

I have tried setting the title explicitly with no avail. Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong here.

---

Here is the code for reference:

// Code for the Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_boy_2"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_pic"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="@string/account_person_name_label"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @azizbekian : The desired output is to have a normal looking Toolbar which displays the text, overflow menu as an unchanged ActionBar does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally. The title from `CollapsibleToolbarLayout` interferes with that of `Toolbar`. So, we disable it and it works fine:

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
```